# How to Auto add comma (,) in text-box with numbers but return value is not initialize in text-box

Tags: javascript

```
<input type="number" name="ram" onkeyup="numberWithCommas(this.value)" id="num"/>
```

This code is showing what is happen in and how to add comma in text-box:

```
<input type="number" name="ram" onkeyup="c(this.value)" id="**num**"/>
<p id="show"></p>
<script>
    function addcomm(x) {
       var parts = x.toString().split(".");
       parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
       document.getElementById('show').innerHTML= parts.join(".");
       //document.getElementById('num').value=parts.join(".");
       return parts.join(".");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: input type of number does not support commas....

Comment: `addcomm` does not match `c`